# Meaning of the phrase "hacked by someone" — but not in context of computers

Tags: meaning, verbs, slang

What does it mean when a girl says that she "hasn't been hacked [by a boy]"? Dictionaries give us only computer-related meanings of "hack"; does it have any other meaning?

Comment: It's not something I've heard before, but I hope it **doesn't** mean that he hasn't *gained access*, unauthorised or otherwise.

Comment: Please provide more context, details about the location and the speaker herself.

Comment: Urban Dictionary definition #37 of _hack_ is: **to kiss someone passionately, snog**. [link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hack&page=6)

Comment: @BillFranke: That sounds more like an answer than a comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem relevant to the specific scenario, but "hacked" is a somewhat common sports term referring to intentionally illegal contact, such as hitting a player's arm in basketball.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a synonym of "tricked"?

Comment: as in, a prostitution setup?

Answer (score -1):

It is generally an intimate meaning, such as kissing or other sensuality.

It derives from

- the computer-related meaning, generally 'to gain access to a system which has barriers to entry' and
- and the challenge that women typically present, to avoid 'being easy'

Comment: My wife tells me that my desktop PC is her most serious rival. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke entendre straight through the 4th wall!